# cakephp Redirect in a controller is not working

Tags: cakephp

I am working on a searching module. When I search some item the slug of that item is passed in a url as a query string but i want to convert it into named parameter. For this I created a `urlToNamed()` action in a custom component RedirectComponent.php. My code is:

```
 RedirectComponent.php

 function urlToNamed() {
    $urlArray = $this->controller->params->query;
    if(!empty($urlArray)){
        #remove unset values
        $urlArray = array_filter($urlArray);
        $this->controller->redirect($urlArray);
    }
}     

 I am calling the urlToNamed() action from index action of BooksController.php i.e


 public function index() { 
    $this->Redirect->urlToNamed();

    //All other stuff to handle named parameter data and show result.
 }
```

The problem is my URL after search the data is as a query string like `http://localhost/esolutions/books/index?category=Books` to which i have to convert into named parameter like `http://localhost/esolutions/books/index/category:Books`.

Another problem is that

```
 $this->controller->redirect($urlArray);
```

is not working. Please give any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the query string parameter to a named parameter? You can use query string parameters in controller actions too.

Comment: Actually I am displaying all products in BooksController by using slug (with a named parameter). Thats why i do not want to change the functionality for search.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change a query string parameter to a named parameter, then I’d just put this functionality in your `index()` action:

```
public function index($category = null) {
    if (isset($this->request->query['category'])) {
        $this->redirect(array('category' => $this->request->query['category']), 301);
    }

    // rest of index code as normal
}
```

That will perform a 301 redirect of any URLs like **/esolutions/books/index/?category=foo** to **/esolutions/books/index/category:foo**.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your efforts. Your code is working and now the code i had posted is also working. Actually the problom was redirect function was not working in my controller. But now its fine.